# Не выводится на хостинге, виджет "по умолчанию" с погодой по местоположению. В чём причина?

Tags: reactjs, redux, геолокация

Всем добрый день. Работаю на реакте, при запуске сервера всё хорошо работает, первоначально на сайте загружается виджет погоды с текущим местоположением, далее можно добавлять нужные города через форму ввода. Но загрузив проект на хостинг первоначальный виджет не загружается - его просто нет, ни ошибок ни запросов на получение местоположения, ничего... не могу понять причину помогите...

код:

```
componentDidMount() {
const toRunWeatherInfo = this.props.weatherInfo; // через редакс доступ к экшенам
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  const {
    coords: { latitude, longitude } // полученные координаты
  } = position;

toRunWeatherInfo(latitude, longitude); // передал в экшен редакса получил объект с погодными данными с api
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Причина была в том, что на хостинге протокол по которому запускался сайт был http, а нужно было https чтобы отрабатывал метод определения текущего местоположения.